# Python shortest distance between a point and a line segment in 3D and intersection point on the segment

Tags: python, distance

I'm looking for a python implementation of the shortest distance between a point and a line segment in 3D and the intersection point on the segment

Comment: What about [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html)?

Comment: @DiTTiD
No, this was an answer for point to point interdistance. I need an implementation for point to line segment distance as mentioned in the title

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implemenation using `numpy`:

```py
def min_distance(r: np.ndarray, a: np.ndarray):
    """ Compute the minimal distance between a point and a segment.

    Given a segment of points xa and xb and a point p

    Parameters
    ----------
    r
        xb - xa

    a
        xa - p

    Returns
    -------
    d
        The minimal distance spanning from p to the segment
    """

    min_t = np.clip(-a.dot(r) / (r.dot(r)), 0, 1)

    d = a + min_t * r

    return np.sqrt(d.dot(d))
```

### Explanation

---

Given a segment, identified by two points `xa` and `xb`, and a generic point `p` . We define the following quantities

[image: a]

[image: r]

A generic point on the segment, has coordinates:

[image: x]

So the distance of the point `p` from  a generic point on the segment is:

[image: d]

We want to minimize the squared distance (we use the squared distance to make calculations a bit easier)

[image: dd]

[image: dd2]

i.e.

[image: ddt]

This gives us the value of `t` that minimizes the distance (actually makes stationary).

[image]

Now we need to remember that we are constrained to keep [image: t01], so we can clamp `t`.

Computing `d(t_min)` will gives the minimum distance.

The distance will be the norm of the returned `d`: `np.linalg.norm(d)` or, equivalently, `np.sqrt(d.dot(d))`.

[image: figure1]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use the [scikit-spatial library](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#).

The point-line distance can be computed in the following way:

```py
from skspatial.objects import Line

line = Line([5, 2, -3], [3, 8, 2])
line_point_distance = line.distance_point([5, -5, 3]).round(3)
```

Then, what you call the intersection point is just the projection of this point onto the line:

```py
point_projected = line.project_point(point)
```

**EDIT**

As @sean rightly observed, the OP is interested in line segments, not infinite lines. Here is the updated code using again the `scikit-spatial` library. Given the two endpoints, a `LineSegment` object is created. The two endpoints are also used to create a infinite line which will be used to project the point onto this line. If the projected point lies on the line segment, then the distance is computed.

```py
from skspatial.objects import Line, Point, LineSegment

endpoint_a = Point([5, 2, -3])
endpoint_b = Point([3, 8, 2])

point = Point([5, -5, 3])

line_segment = LineSegment(endpoint_a, endpoint_b)

line = Line.from_points(endpoint_a, endpoint_b)

projected_point = line.project_point(point)

if line_segment.contains_point(projected_point):
    distance = line.distance_point(point)
```

Comment: This assumes that the line is infinite, the second argument to Line is the direction not the end point. The library does have a LineSegment object (representing a finite line between two points) but I couldn't find an associated line_segment.distance_point function.